# Threads in Java Swing, overview of three approaches in an application

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, desktop

I'm using the code bellow in a desktop swing application, and I don't have much expertise 
with threads, because I'm a casual web programmer and deal with swing isn't my candy...

I want to know if have better approach to control my 3 tasks and I need running them in parallel one for thread in my app.

```
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            task 1                
         }
    });


    Runnable r;
    r = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            task 2                  
        }
    };
    EventQueue.invokeLater(r);


    Thread worker = new Thread() {

        public void run() {
            task 3                 
        }
    };

    worker.start();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What are you trying to do? Does your thread operate in the Swing GUI or is it independent of the GUI?

You should use [`invokeLater()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) if the thread is doing something with the Swing user interface, because that can only be done from [the Event Dispatch Thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). Swing is single-threaded. (Your task 1 and 2)

If you are doing something completely in the background e.g. writing a large XML-file, that can be done in a background [thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html). (Your task 3) But you can still communicate with the Swing GUI using `invokeLater()`.

Another alternative is if you want to run a thread regularly, e.g. every 5th minute, you can use a [TimerTask](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). Or if it's independent of the Swing GUI [java.util.TimerTask](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html).

**[Concurrency in Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)** might be worth reading:

> A Swing programmer deals with the following kinds of threads:
>
> - *Initial threads*, the threads that execute initial application code.
> - *The event dispatch thread*, where all event-handling code is executed. Most code that interacts with the Swing framework must also execute on this thread.
> - *Worker threads*, also known as background threads, where time-consuming background tasks are executed.

Answer (score 7):

#1 and #2 are the same. You should use number #1 since that's the well-known part of the API.

Whether you use #1 or #3 depends on the following:

Is it making changes to the user interface or its backing models? 
If yes, use #1.

Is it a long-running task:
If yes, use #3.

If it is a long-running task that will eventually modify the user interface or its backing model, perform the long running task in a separate thread, and then call incokeLater to update the user interface.

Furthermore, instead of creating a new thread every time, use an ExecutorService so you can reuse threads.

It can get a little bit more complicated, for example, if you're currently in the event thread (ie: in an `ActionListener.actionPerformed()`, then you don't need to (as in shouldn't) call invokeLater, but the gist of it is up there.

Comment: agreed with everything except the "as in shouldn't" call invokeLater in listener callbacks that are (normally) guaranteed to run on the EDT: doing so will invoke the task _after_ all pending events are done, so it effects to sequence of doing stuff

Comment: If you doing a long running task that will eventually modify the user interface, then SwingWorker is a good choice over creating your own thread or using an executor service directly.